# Ant Mail-Task - X-Auto-Response-Suppress header

Tags: email, ant, jakarta-mail

I got some old jobs which are sending mails via an Ant Mail Task (`Ant 1.7.1`) using the JavaMail Library (`JavaMail 1.5.0`). Now the sender shouldn't receive any automated response mails.

For some reasons the `Reply-To` header is ignored by the Exchange Server / Outlook and I don't know if / how I can set the `Return-Path` header in the Ant Task.

So the easiest way would be to just set the `X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All` header.

Is that possible in the named `Ant` version?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaMail you can set the return path header via the 'mail.smtp.from' session property.